# Rails_admin deleting few items in one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Is it possible to delete a few items with one click? I have installed rails_admin for my site. When i view list of some items, for example "users" i could select a few of them with selectbox in left side of each item. Then in the top i see button called "Selected items" but click on this button doesn't do anything, just page refresh. Should i manually add some code to allow any actions for this button?

**Update:**

Well, i just notice that this function works ok on local server, but doesn't work on production on DO. It looks that some ajax call, or js function problem, but i don't get any errors in console.
Here is code of my rails_admin.rb file if it would help to suggest me something:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.sidescroll = true
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user && current_user.admin == true
  end
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     
    index                         
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app    
  end
end
```

Comment: You can check the logs in your terminal what it does when you click the "Selected items" button. You say it does nothing but just a page refresh, I don't think it's that simple. In the logs you can see if it does a `GET` or `POST` request and with what params.

Comment: @Hackman The most strange is that this works ok on local. But on production on live server it doesn't works, but also doesn't throw error into console. I also have checked log files but didn't find there any errors connected with it.

Comment: The problem is probably in `RailsAdmin`'s assets. Check if any other JS is working on the page. If not, you should find out why the assets are not precompiled.

Comment: @chumakoff what could you suggest in this case?

Comment: Try adding this to 'config/initializers/assets.rb':  `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['rails_admin/rails_admin.css', 'rails_admin/rails_admin.js']`

Comment: @chumakoff Tried. Also tried to add it in application.rb but no changes